# Getting hot reloading to work with Electron and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm working on an Electron project with TypeScript and am having difficulties implementing hot-reloading. I want to automatically reload the Electron app whenever there are changes to the `src/` directory.

I've tried both `electron-reload` and `electron-reloader`, but neither seem to pick up on changes I'm making to the TS files.

Are there any proven methods to get hot reloading to work in an Electron + TypeScript setup? Is there an example repo I can clone?

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**: My app is based on [Electron's official Typescript quickstart repo](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript).

Comment: What do you use to bundle your app? Webpack? Vte? Something else? Your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm just compiling my app using `tsc` and running it with the `electron` command (`electron ./dist/main.js`). See also the edit to the question